# How to use phalcon createbuilder for join multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, phalcon

here is the working code for displaying rows from 3 different tables using **PHQL**. i want to code the same using `$this->modelsManager->createBuilder()`. Please find working code and error below.

Controller

```
<?php
    $phql  = 'SELECT product.*, currency.*, unittype.* FROM product LEFT JOIN currency ON product.CurrencyId=currency.Id LEFT JOIN unittype ON product.UnitTypeId=unittype.Id ORDER BY product.Name ASC';
    $query = $this->modelsManager->createQuery($phql);
    $this->view->products = $query->execute();
?>
```

View

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Unit Type</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Currency</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($products as $row)    { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row->product->Name; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->product->Description; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->unittype->Name; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->product->Price; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->currency->Code; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->tag->linkTo('product/edit/'.$row->product->Id,'Edit'); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->tag->linkTo('product/delete/'.$row->product->Id,'Delete'); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

> I wanted to use createbuilder from modelmanager; how to writequery and
>   print in view?
>
> below is the code i wrote and having issue:

Controller

```
<?php
    $this->view->products = $this->modelsManager->createBuilder()
        ->from('product')
        ->innerjoin('currency','product.CurrencyId=currency.Id')
        ->orderBy('product.Name')
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
?>
```

View

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Unit Type</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Currency</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($products as $product)    { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $product->Name; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $product->Description; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $product->UnitTypeId; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $product->Price; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $product->currency->Id; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->tag->linkTo('product/edit/'.$product->Id,'Edit'); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->tag->linkTo('product/delete/'.$product->Id,'Delete'); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

***Above code producing following error:***

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\wamp\www\xxxx.volt.php on line xx

Comment: Which line is `xx`? Have you tried a `<?php die(var_dump($products)) ?>` to see if you are returning any data?

Comment: @PaulSCoder yes it's returning empty array

Comment: @PaulSCoder if you need my full source code you can find here https://github.com/syednizamudeen/invoice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in your controller. The resulting data should be a `Resultset`

```
$builder = $this->modelsManager->createBuilder();

$builder
    ->columns(
        [
            'Product.Id'          => 'productId',
            'Product.Name'        => 'productName',
            'Product.Description' => 'productDescription',
            'Unittype.Name'       => 'unitTypeName',
            'Product.Price'       => 'productPrice',
            'Currency.Code'       => 'Currency.Code',
        ]
    )
    ->addFrom('Product')
    ->leftJoin('Currency', 'Product.CurrencyId = Currency.Id')
    ->leftJoin('Unittype', 'Product.UnitTypeId = Unittype.Id')
    ->orderBy('Product.Name')
    ->getQuery();

$data = $builder->execute();

var_dump($data);
```

This will return only the fields you have in your view.

Comment: `<?php
   $builder = $this->modelsManager->createBuilder()
   ->columns(
    [
     'ProductId'          => 'product.Id',
     'ProductName'        => 'product.Name',
     'ProductDescription' => 'product.Description',
     'UnittypeName'       => 'unittype.Name',
     'ProductPrice'       => 'product.Price',
     'CurrencyCode'       => 'currency.Code',
    ]
   )
   ->addFrom('product')
   ->leftJoin('currency', 'product.CurrencyId = currency.Id')
   ->leftJoin('unittype', 'product.UnitTypeId = unittype.Id')
   ->orderBy('product.Name')
   ->getQuery()
   ->execute();
  ?>`